# creating dynamic resizable layout based on content

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I am trying to create a layout, that shows current 3 hour lessons along with the time and date with room number.

possible screens:
[image]

The room and time/date is always static at the top and the rest would be dynamic from calls in  SQL from JSON.

```
data = idleResponse.getJSONArray("lecture");
                ArrayList<String> lects = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jObj = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String time = jObj.getString("startTime"); // to do.substring(0, 4);
                    String moduleName = jObj.getString("moduleName");
                    lects.add(time + " " + moduleName);
                }               
                String[] lectureList = new String[lects.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i<lects.size();i++){
                    // fill with data
                    lectureList[i] = lects.get(i);
                }                           
                lecture.setText("Upcomming Lectures:");
                //set to list view
                ListView listitems=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lectureList);
                listitems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I tried to implement this with a list view, however it just shrinks down to a small section of the screen based on number of elements.

[image]

as you can see it just shrinks down.

I was wondering what would be the best type of layout to use for this type of problem, all of my layouts are pretty basic and something like this seems quite a challenge for me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own Adapter for listview and use weight property for layout of each row